# How to extend a class in python?

Tags: python, class, interface

In python how can you extend a class? For example if I have

color.py

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def getcolor(self):
        return self.color
```

color_extended.py

```
import Color

class Color:
    def getcolor(self):
        return self.color + " extended!"
```

But this doesn't work...
I expect that if I work in `color_extended.py`, then when I make a color object and use the `getcolor` function then it will return the object with the string " extended!" in the end. Also it should have gotton the init from the import.

Assume python 3.1

Comment: Did you try to read documentation?  http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: classes should have first letter capitalized ("Color" not "color") ;)

Comment: @wRAR Maybe in 2013 this is a reasonable question, but let's be honest - people turn to StackOverflow first, so this is a good question to have on SO. This question is the first google hit for "python extend class", the documentation is third.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use:

```
import color

class Color(color.Color):
    ...
```

If this were Python 2.x, you would also want to derive `color.Color` from `object`, to make it a [new-style class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python):

```
class Color(object):
    ...
```

This is not necessary in Python 3.x.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can give the new class the same name as the old one: `class color(color):` defines a new class that replaces the old one, but which is derived from it. (This seems to be what the OP is trying to do.)

Comment: `class extended_color(color):` is bad standards usually - `class ExtendedColor(Color):` should be for classes. Just a nitpick

Comment: Noob question here: why didn't you use `__init__`?

Comment: @Mentalist - Since the approach is basing a new custom class named `Color` on the existing `Color` class in the `color` module, you only need to implement overload definitions. E.g. if you don't implement an `__init__()` method in your new class but there is one in the class you're basing yours off of, it will just use the base class's `__init__()` method.

Comment: This makes a new class. It does not extend the old.

Answer (score 20):

```
class MyParent:

    def sayHi():
        print('Mamma says hi')
```

```
from path.to.MyParent import MyParent

class ChildClass(MyParent):
    pass
```

An instance of `ChildClass` will then inherit the `sayHi()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to extend (specifically meaning, add new methods, not change existing ones) classes, even built-in ones, is to use a preprocessor that adds the ability to extend out of/above the scope of Python itself, converting the extension to normal Python syntax before Python actually gets to see it.

I've done this to extend Python 2's `str()` class, for instance. `str()` is a particularly interesting target because of the implicit linkage to quoted data such as `'this'` and `'that'`.

Here's some extending code, where the only added non-Python syntax is the `extend:testDottedQuad` bit:

```
extend:testDottedQuad
def testDottedQuad(strObject):
    if not isinstance(strObject, basestring): return False
    listStrings = strObject.split('.')
    if len(listStrings) != 4: return False
    for strNum in listStrings:
        try:    val = int(strNum)
        except: return False
        if val < 0: return False
        if val > 255: return False
    return True
```

After which I can write in the code fed to the preprocessor:

```
if '192.168.1.100'.testDottedQuad():
    doSomething()

dq = '216.126.621.5'
if not dq.testDottedQuad():
    throwWarning();

dqt = ''.join(['127','.','0','.','0','.','1']).testDottedQuad()
if dqt:
    print 'well, that was fun'
```

The preprocessor eats that, spits out normal Python without monkeypatching, and Python does what I intended it to do.

Just as a c preprocessor adds functionality to c, so too can a Python preprocessor add functionality to Python.

My preprocessor implementation is too large for a stack overflow answer, but for those who might be interested, it is [here](https://github.com/fyngyrz/pyex) on GitHub.

Comment: This is very cool.  Use this in Swift all the time, wish Python did this natively, though there is too much toolchain baggage I suspect.  Also, an actual answer to the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

I use it like this.

```
class menssagem:
  propriedade1 = "Certo!"
  propriedade2 = "Erro!"

def metodo1(self)
  print(self.propriedade1)
```

to extend.

```
import menssagem
class menssagem2(menssagem):

  menssagem1 = None #não nescessario not necessary

  def __init__(self,menssagem):
    self.menssagem1 = menssagem

  #call first class method
  #usando o metodo da menssagem 1

  def Menssagem(self):
    self.menssagem1.metodo1()
```

Comment: Translate the comments from Portuguese to English so everybody can understand you please :)