# Python Date Class Methods

Tags: python, function, class, date, methods

brand new here!

This is my first time working with Python classes and I am a bit confused. I wanted to try and store dates with three attributes - year, month, and day (as integers).

What I want to do is:

for an ____init____() function to take a year, month and a date (with defaults 1900, 1 and 1) and return it with the month written out:

```
>>date_one = Date( 1973, 5, 2)
May 2, 1973
>>date_two = Date( 1984)
January 1, 1984
```

for a ____str____() function to format the data as a string with year, month, and day:

```
>>date_one = Date( 1973, 5, 2)
>>string = str(date_one)
>>string
'1973-05-02'
>>date_two = Date( 1984)
>>print date_two
1984-01-01
```

for same_date_in_year() to determine whether two dates fall on the same date, even if they aren't in the same year

```
>>date_one = Date( 1972, 3, 27)
>>date_two = Date( 1998, 4, 17)
>>date_three = Date(1957, 4, 17)
>>date_one.same_date_in_year(date_two)
False
>>date_two.same_date_in_year(date_three)
True
```

What I have so far:

```
days_in_month = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

month_names = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

class Date(object):
    year = 1900
    month = 1
    day = 1

    def __init__(self, year=1900, month=1, day=1):
        self.year, self.month, self.day = year, month, day
        print month_names[month], str(day)+', '+str(year)

    def __str__(self, year=1900, month=1, day=1):
        self.year, self.month, self.day = year, month, day
        print str(year)+'-'+str(month).rjust(2,'0')+'-'+str(day).rjust(2,'0')


    def same_date_in_year(year, month, day):

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    date_one = Date( 1972, 3, 27 )
    date_two = Date( 1998, 4, 13 )
    date_three = Date( 1996, 4, 13 )
    print "date_one is " + str(date_one)
    print "date_two is " + str(date_two)
    print "date_three is " + str(date_three)
    print "date_one.same_day_in_year(date_two)", date_one.same_day_in_year(date_two)
    print "date_two.same_day_in_year(date_three)", date_two.same_day_in_year(date_three)
    print
```

I have no idea how the Class would work and the functions inside it, before the pass. If someone could help me, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. I think most people would be happy to help you with *specific* questions, but nobody wants to do all your homework for you. So break your big problem down into smaller ones and ask those instead.

Comment: I would be happy with just the __init__ function. I just want to understand how classes work.

Comment: A class's initializer shouldn't "return" or "print out" a value; it just should return an instance of that class. You can then add a `__repr__` method to that class so that, when someone tries to look at an instance of it, they see what you want instead of `<__main__.Date at 0x12345678>`.

Comment: Anyway, the Tutorial chapter on [Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) explains this far better than a random StackOverflow user is liable to, with multiple examples. For example, the [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) section shows a perfectly simple but real-life example of an `__init__` method for a `Complex` class.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think this deserves to be closed, and therefore not answered, because it's not appropriate for StackOverflow. But it's not a bad question in general, just wrong for SO, and an example of what you want is so trivial to write, so I wrote it [here](http://pastebin.com/yKWwBgwF). Some of the details are probably not right, but you should be able to use that as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you! So, __init__ is working but do you have any idea why __str__ isn't printing after every run-through of __name__ (I edited it).

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your comment, you're looking for some help with the `init` method, and may be able to finish the rest off on your own.

```py
class MDate(Object):
  """Example Date class for learning purposes. Note the prefix 'M' in the
     class name to avoid conflicts with built-in classes."""
  def __init__(self, year=1900, month=1, day=1):
    for arg in [year, month, day]:
      if type(arg) != int:
        raise TypeException('Year, month, and day must be `int`')

    self.year = year
    self.month = month
    self.day = day
```

Comment: You should add the default values into the arguments `year=1900, month=1, day=1`

Comment: Will do, accidentally posted this too early, thanks.

Comment: This returns me with a `<__main__.MDate object at 0x025648B0>`

Comment: You need a `__repr__` method as well in order to show the date object in the interpreter in the format you want.

Answer (score -1):

I am somewhat new to Python as well. May I suggest the following solution where you simply extend a date class that is already available in Python? Python has "[batteries included](http://www.protocolostomy.com/2010/01/22/what-batteries-included-means/)" which means you do not have to repeat yourself by taking advantage of the Standard Library.

When first learning Python, I found myself constantly reinventing the wheel, or date object in this case, until I understood the concept of [extending a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526858/how-to-extend-a-class-in-python).

```
# import date type from modules included with Python install
from datetime import date


class Date(date):  # extend the date type imported above
    # some date formats, see http://strftime.org/ for values
    year_month_day = "%Y %m %d"
    month_day_year = "%m %d %Y"

    # *args and **kwargs are the arguments and key word arguments
    # passed when date object is created
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # set a default string_format from choices defined above
        # that is used in the __str__ and __repr__ functions
        self.string_format = self.year_month_day
        # call the __init__ on parent `date` object
        # passing all args and kwargs passed on object creation
        # at date = Date(1970, 1, 1)
        super(Date, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        # date has a function called `strftime` that takes
        # a string format and returns the formatted date
        return self.strftime(self.string_format)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime(self.string_format)
```

Example usage of extended class:

> In: date_one = Date(1970, 1, 1)
>
> In: print date_one
>
> # as defined by date.string_format  value "%Y %m %d"
>
> Out: 1970 01 01
>
> # change the string_format value to "%m %d %Y"
>
> In: date_one.string_format = date_one.month_day_year
>
> In: print date_one
>
> Out: 01 01 1970

You can also set a string format like so:

> In: date_one.string_format = "%c"
>
> In: print date_one
>
> Out: Thu Jan  1 00:00:00
> 1970

This link on [special methods overriding in Python](http://lgiordani.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/#.VUBwLa1VhBc) may be helpful.