# Is it possible to define additional class methods in another module?

Tags: python, class, methods

I wonder if anything like this is possible in Python. Say that in a library, there is a class `X` defined with methods `a`, `b` and `c`:

```py
class X:
  def a(self):
     ...
  def b(self):
     ...
  def c(self):
     ...
```

I would like to add a method `custom` into the class `X` (so that I can then call `X().custom()`) without modifying the library code.

I know I could do something like

```py
def custom(self):
   ...
X.custom = custom
```

but doing it this way does not look very nice.

Is there any more intelligent way of achieving what I want (for example similar to `impl` on structs in Rust)?

Comment: Why not subclass it and add methods there?

Comment: you can inherit it.

Comment: True, I am probably just overworked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using python3, import the library then expand the class as explained below-
Assuming the parent code (where class X is written) was in main.py then we can do something like this -

```
import main

class X(main.X):

    def custom():
        print("hello hi")
        #your code
```

For details, you may refer- [How to extend a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526858/how-to-extend-a-class-in-python)